# I want to replace a string using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got a string which I want to replace by `preg_replace`. Since I'm relatively new to `preg_replace`, when I see how I can do this one, it will help me a lot to replace all other strings in my project.

```
//example1:
$string = '<a title="" href="#_ftnref1">[1]</a>';
$newStr = '<img title="Anchor 1" src="anch.png" id="1">';

//example2:
$string = '<a title="" href="#_ftnref324">[324]</a>';
$newStr = '<img title="Anchor 324" src="anch.png" id="324">';
```

What you see in the first line `$string`, there are numbers in it. Per string, these numbers are always the same.. but they differ in length in another string (as you can see in the second example).

I've already managed to replace it using `strpos`, `str_replace` etc... but `preg_replace` will be more efficient. Beside that, I really want to learn `preg_replace`

Comment: `preg_replace` must use a regular expression compilation engine. That's a much bigger computational effort than running up and down a string.

Comment: Can you show examples of how you've tried to use `preg_replace` to solve this? At the moment, you're just asking for code to be written for you.

Comment: It covers a lot of strings in my whole document, that means that I have to use a for loop for each string I want to replace. The $string above is just one of the formats i need to replace. I'm not sure but I thought preg_replace would be more efficient in this case.

Comment: `preg_replace` would be more efficient... no. `preg_replace` would be more *flexible*... yes.

Comment: @Pudge601 I know, I already did a preg_replace on a div to take out all <div> and </div> tags, that one works fine, but I don't see where to start with this one. Hope there is some 'freak' out there who loves to solve these things :). Still I'll keep on trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you

```
preg_replace('/<a .*?>\[([0-9]+)\]<\/a>/', '<img title="Anchor \1" src="anch.png" id="\1">', $input_lines);
```

the \1 in the replace string means the first group ([0-9]+)

Comment: You forgot to escape the quotes there. Also, `\d` =)

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'll go and see how the magic does it's job! :)